# Show homeomorphism between convex hull and unit ball?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

In the proof of Schauder fixed point theorem in Evans' PDE book, he uses a claim that the convex hull $K$ of $N$ points $x_1,\dots,x_N$ in a convex compact subset $A$ of a Banach space $X$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^M$ with $M\leq N$. Can someone show me why or provide some reference on the proof of this claim?

Comment: Convex polytopes have the same topological genus as the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search yields the following document:

http://relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/geschke/papers/ConvexOpen.pdf

I am sure you can modify this method of proof to prove exactly what you want.